# More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'SMSApp'. Specify the name of the one to use

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am developing a mvc 5 application using code first approach.

i am facing an issue . at first time when i try below comands , it worked and generate the table in that database. but when i changed some more classes and then tried with first 2 queries , it worked in that case but when i tried the third command, it gave this message to me.

```
First step
==========

enable-migrations -ContextTypeName IdentityDb -MigrationsDirectory DAL\IdentityMigrations

enable-migrations -ContextTypeName SMSContext -MigrationsDirectory DAL\SMSMigrations

Second Step
===========

add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName SMSApp.DAL.IdentityMigrations.Configuration "InitialCreate"

add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName SMSApp.DAL.SMSMigrations.Configuration "InitialCreate"

Third Step
==========

update-database -ConfigurationTypeName SMSApp.DAL.IdentityMigrations.Configuration -verbose

update-database -ConfigurationTypeName SMSApp.DAL.SMSMigrations.Configuration -verbose
```

see the first error:

```
PM> add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName SMSApp.DAL.IdentityMigrations.Configuration "InitialCreate"
Scaffolding migration ' '.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration InitialCreate' again.

A previous migration called 'InitialCreate' was already applied to the target database. If you meant to re-scaffold 'InitialCreate', revert it by running 'Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase', then delete '201409261933262_InitialCreate1.cs' and run 'Add-Migration InitialCreate' again.
```

After that i executed the below command, it gave the below exception.

Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase -verbose

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase -verbose
Using StartUp project 'SMSApp'.
Using NuGet project 'SMSApp'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException: More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'SMSApp'. Specify the name of the one to use.
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeFinder.FindType(Type baseType, String typeName, Func`2 filter, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'SMSApp'. Specify the name of the one to use.
```

NOw i am worry how to resolve it?

Comment: Post your Web.config and Configuration/Migrations.cs and if you have data context or initilizers anywhere else post them too.

Answer (score 37):

You need to specify which configuration you want to use when updating the databases.

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MyRenamedConfiguration
```

Comment: You can also used a shorten notation:
Update-Database -Configuration MyRenamedConfiguration
or even
Update-Database -Config MyRenamedConfiguration
or any abbreviation that is unique eg.
Update-Database -Conf MyRenamedConfiguration

Answer (score -2):

Enable

- Migrations
- ContextTypeName DropDownList_plus_Crud_project.User_Complete
- MigrationsDirectory Migrations.Identity

  1. If First DBContext is added already in your project then you have to add the second DBContext.
  2. Go to Tool>Nuget-Package-Console.
  3. Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ProjectName.DBContextName -MigrationsDirectory NameofFile Which you want to create
  4. Successfully Created 2nd Migration in your project.

[image]